# Replace string with multiple variation

Tags: php

I would like to replace some text in a string, however, it has multiple variation.

I have multiple string to replace and I'm looping it to replace it one by one.. for example..

```
$string1 = 'select * from table where id = :id';
$string2 = 'select * from table where id =:id';
$string3 = 'select * from table where id =  :id';
```

and so on...

I'm tyring to replace "id = :id" with "id in (:id)".
So for $string1, the results should be '`select * from table where id in (:id)`' and the same for other strings.

However, each variable are different, this `id = :id` could be `id=:id` or `id=  :id`... and some has different spacing...

currently, Im using this code below, but didnt realize, some of the variables has more than one spaces...

```
$sql = str_replace(array("=:id", "= :id"), " in (:id)", $string);
```

Is is possible to do this without replacing each of the variable manually by removing excessive spaces? I'm trying to avoid doing it manually because i'm getting those variable from the database and some people would input to the database with excessive spaces and I have no control of it.

Comment: what's the motivation behind this? isn't it that pdo does this too?

Comment: @Kevin im trying to replace '=' with 'in'.. not sure how pdo can replace this ?

Comment: just count the number of payload in a prepared statement with pdo, and put question mark placeholders `id IN (?, ?, ?)` if lets say 3 id inputs. no need to make string manipulations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [preg_replace](https://php.net/preg_replace) to replace them all independently of how many spaces they contains:

```
$sql = preg_replace("/ *= *:id/", " in (:id)", $string);
```

You can try it in this [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/l77LBE/1).

Comment: hi, how come i have an error... Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'in' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' i

EDIT: oh nvm, I've fixed it, thanks !... it works perfectly !

Comment: There was a wrong `"` , retry with the current code in my answer.

Comment: preg_replace("/ *= *:id/", " in (:id)", $string);

Comment: @nodeffect ah! sorry, remove the `)`, see my edit. I tested it, works.